# If $f \in L_2(a,b)$, then $\int_a^x f(y) dy \in L_2(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $f \in L_2(a,b)$, then I want to show that the antiderivative
$$
 F(x) := \int_a^x f(y) d y
$$
is in $L_2$ (I guess this is true). If $L_2(a,b)$ would be closed under pointwise product, i.e. if $f,g \in L_2$, then $f\cdot g \in L_2$, then this would follow easily, but I guess this is not true. So any hints how to show the closure under taking antiderivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $F(x) = \int_a^b 1_{[a,x]}(y)f(y)\, dy$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$|F(x)| \le  \|1_{[a,x]}\|_2\cdot\|f\|_2 = (x - a)^{1/2}\|f\|_2 \qquad (a < x < b).$$ Thus $$\|F\|_2 \le  \|(x - a)^{1/2}\|_2\cdot \|f\|_2 = \frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2}}\|f\|_2 < \infty.$$

Comment: Thank you, now I solved it. But let me note that I used a more general version of Minkowski then the usual one $||f + g||_p \le ||f||_p + ||g||_p$ which I did not know beforehand. You can find it on wikipedia under the headline "Minkowski's integral inequality".

Comment: Minkowski's integral inequality is the one I meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: After some time I found a simpler approach, just using Cauchy-Schwarz. Am I missing something? It goes like this: Let $a < x <b$, then \begin{align*} |F(x)| & = |\int_a^b f(y) 1_{[a,x]} dy| \\ & \le \int_a^b |f(y)| 1_{[a,x]}(y) dy \\ & = \langle |f|, 1_{[a,x]} \rangle \\ & \le ||f||_2 \cdot || 1_{[a,x]} || \\ & = ||f||_2 (x - a) \end{align*} and so $ ||F(x)||_2^2 \le \int_a^c ||f||_2 (x-a)^2 dx \in L_2(a,b)$, where the last term is contained in $L_2(a,b)$ because it is simply a polynomial. Seems way simpler then applying the general Minkowski inequality, but maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: Note $\|1_{[a,x]}\|_2 = (x - a)^{1/2}$, not $x - a$. Keep in mind that $\|F(x)\|_2^2$ is a constant, not variable -- the goal was to show that $F$, not $\|F(x)\|_2^2$, is in $L_2(a,b)$. Would you like me to give you a purely Cauchy-Schwarz proof instead?

Comment: I am still confused, we have $$ || F ||_2^2 = \int_a^b |F(x)|^2 d x \le \int_a^b ||f||_2^2 (x - a) d x $$ by monotonicity of the integral, and so this approach seems to work for me. And yes, $F(x) \in \mathbb R$, so writting $||F(x)||_2^2$ is strictly the norm of a constant, but that is not what I meant there... (btw your purely Cauchy-Schwarz proof would be of interest)

Comment: The comment that contained your proof was confusing (near the end), but you were on the right track. In any case, I'll change my answer and give the CS-proof.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not see what should be missing in my proof.